# syntax to check a value in a if statement in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The following code gives me an error, can you help me know where is the syntax problem ?

Code in the controller :

```
if (in_array($request->get('post_type'), ['newQ', 'newP'])) {
    $category = implode(",", $request->get('catBox'));
} else {
    $category = $request->get('catBox');
}
```

Error :

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 747: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array in helpers.php line 747 at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array', 'D:\wamp\www\testSite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php', '747', array('search' => '\?', 'replace' => array('test', array('appliances', 'Development'), 'Qtop', '1', '2016-06-21 07:46:34', '2016-06-21 07:46:34'), 'subject' => 'insert into posts (body, cat, post_type, user_id, updated_at, created_at) values (test, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 'value' => array('appliances', 'Development')))

Comment: There is no preg_replace in the code you gave us.

Comment: Can you post your view file?

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://jakzaprogramowac.pl/pytanie/20922,laravel-5-2-errorexception-preg-replace-parameter-mismatch-pattern-is-a-string-while-replacement-is-an-array) or [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/preg-replace-parameter-mismatch-error) as there seem to be many other laravel users with this problem. Also please don't post the same question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934169/parameter-mismatch-pattern-is-a-string-while-replacement-is-an-array-laravel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **you need to post more code / context** in your questions. You are essentially duplicating [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934169/parameter-mismatch-pattern-is-a-string-while-replacement-is-an-array-laravel) which is rude.

Second, your error is related to a failed database query. It seems that you are submitting values with an array `['appliances', 'Development']` where you should not. Your HTML form likely has an array and you are only accounting for this in some cases. Try this code:

```
if (in_array($request->get('post_type'), ['newQ', 'newP'])) {
    $category = implode(",", $request->get('catBox'));
} else {
    $category = implode(",", $request->get('catBox'));
}
```

### How To Debug Your Error

Let's make your error more readable.

```
HandleExceptions->handleError(
    '2',
    'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array',
    'D:\wamp\www\testSite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php',
    '747', 
    array(
        'search' => '\?',
        'replace' => array(
            'test',
            array('appliances', 'Development'),
            'Qtop',
            '1',
            '2016-06-21 07:46:34',
            '2016-06-21 07:46:34'
        ),
        'subject' => 'insert into posts (body, cat, post_type, user_id, updated_at, created_at) values (test, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        'value' => array('appliances', 'Development')
    )
);
```

A little searching reveals that `HandleExceptions` is a Laravel class. [The Laravel API docs has a full specification](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.html#method_handleError). In the doc we see that it takes a `$context`. `$context` is what was happening when the error occurred.

Let's look at `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php` on line 747. We find:

```
/**
 * Replace a given value in the string sequentially with an array.
 *
 * @param  string  $search
 * @param  array   $replace
 * @param  string  $subject
 * @return string
 */
function str_replace_array($search, array $replace, $subject)
{
    foreach ($replace as $value) {
        $subject = preg_replace('/'.$search.'/', $value, $subject, 1);
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

When comparing the error message to the `str_replace_array()` we can see that every variable and a value are shown in the error message. Since PHP stopped working we can assume that the values are the last value before the error, so one of them is the value that triggered the error.

In the error message we see:

> preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Let's determine what "pattern" and "replacement" are by looking at the [PHP: preg_replace - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Clearly they are the function arguments `$pattern` and `$replacement`.

Looking back at the `str_replace_array()` we can see that in the error message `$search` is `$pattern` and `$value` is `$replacement`.

Now the error message should make more sense. `$pattern` is a string `'\?'` while `$replacement` is an array `array('appliances', 'Development')`.